# Find rows based on two coloumns in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

So I have this problem where I need to find the rows where a coloumn have a specfic value. The table I use is created like this:

```
select table.CID, table2.PID

from table

inner join table2 on table2.OID = table.OID
```

The table looks like this:

```
+------------ table --------------+
|____table.CID___|___table2.PID___|  
|       AA       |       47       |  
|       AA       |       25       |  
|       AA       |       13       |  
|       AA       |       18       |  
|       AB       |       22       |  
|       AB       |       89       |  
|       AC       |       47       |
|       AC       |       15       |
|       AC       |        8       |
+---------------------------------+
```

Now I want to get all rows where table.CID is equal and it has atleast one table.PID that is 47. Results in:

```
 +------------ table --------------+
|____table.CID___|___table2.PID___|  
|       AA       |       47       |  
|       AA       |       25       |  
|       AA       |       13       |  
|       AA       |       18       |  
|       AC       |       47       |
|       AC       |       15       |
|       AC       |        8       |
+---------------------------------+
```

How would one do this? I've tried with `where exists` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query finds the rows with `47`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable JOIN Table2 USING (OID)
WHERE Table2.PID = 47;
```

The `CID` values of these rows can then be used to filter the original query:

```
SELECT MyTable.CID, Table2.PID
FROM MyTable JOIN Table2 USING (OID)
WHERE MyTable.CID IN (SELECT MyTable.CID
                      FROM MyTable JOIN Table2 USING (OID)
                      WHERE Table2.PID = 47);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t2.cid = t.cid and t2.pid = 47);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that table does not have PID as a coloumn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want rows with multiple matched rows from table.cid:

```
SELECT table.CID, table2.PID
FROM table INNER JOIN table2 on table2.OID = table.OID
WHERE ( SELECT count(*) 
        FROM table tt INNER JOIN table2 tt2 ON tt2.OID = tt.OID 
        WHERE tt.cid = table.cid ) > 1
   And Exists ( SELECT 1 
                FROM table2 tt2 WHERE tt2.OID = table.OID And tt2.pid = 47 )
```